# Grails Domain Embedded

Tags: grails-orm, grails-domain-class

I have this domain model, `grails-app/domain`, named `com.portal.Schedule.groovy` having this properties:

```
Subject subject 
Room room
Day day
Time timeStart
Time timeEnd    
static embedded = ['timeStart', 'timeEnd']
```

Where in the object `com.portal.Time` is located in the `src/groovy` having this properties:

```
Integer hour
Integer minute
public Time(Integer hour, Integer minute) {
   super();
   this.hour = hour;
   this.minute = minute;
}
```

The problem is when I want to add a record using the `BootStrap.groovy` having this syntax:

```
new Schedule(subject: Subject.get(1), room: Room.get(1), day: Day.MON,
   timeStart: new Time(9, 0), timeEnd: new Time(11, 00)).save(failOnError: true)
```

I get this error message prior to finish to start-up:

> Message: No default constructor for entity: com.portal.Time; nested
>   exception is org.hibernate.InstantiationException: No default
>   constructor for entity: com.portal.Time

How can I resolve this to have my `Bootstrap.groovy` running with the instance of `Schedule` with those attributes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've searched it thoroughly on Google how to solve this problem.
It's seems `groovy` has almost the same feature with `python` regarding constructor or in other terms `tuples` in Python located [here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/transform/TupleConstructor.html)

After inserting the annotation to the class `Time` I can now code the constructor in multiple ways.

Answer (score 1):

Your Time constructor is set to private.  That's why you're getting that error.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I get the same error after changing the access of the constructor from private to public.